# extracting values from a file to create a bar graph using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need some help with creating this graph using matplotlib.

This is where the event id and the count are being extracted from:

[image: this is where the event id and the count are being extracted from]

I need to create a graph. For this I have attempted some code for this but I keep getting errors as there are lists to extract and I am honestly quite confused and this is the code I have done so far:

```py
def plotnew():
    event = []
    eventcount = []

    with open("path here", 'r') as visualise:
        for line in visualise:
            if line.startswith("Event ID: "):
                event.append(line.split([2]))
            elif line.startswith("Count:"):
                eventcount.append(int(line.split()[2]))

    plt.barh(event, eventcount)
    plt.xlabel('Event Count')
    plt.ylabel('Event ID')
    plt.title('EventID Count')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

I have tried to add [3] after the line split to get the count value or event id but I keep getting errors all over the place and I am quite confused.

Comment: What errors are you getting? What do the variables `eve` and `eventcount` return after your for loop has completed?

Comment: @DerekO TypeError: the dtypes of parameters y (object) and height (float64) are incompatible - this is one of them and its because they are in a list and i do not know how to fix this issue

Comment: @JohanC i have amended it sorry about that and I tried it with 2 and I get this error now TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @JohanC i need to make a simple bar graph with the extracted data e.g. in the image I have given but I keep getting errors I do not know what to do

Comment: @JohanC after i changed that thanks for pointing it out now I get this error:   TypeError: must be str or None, not list

Comment: Why are you writing `line.split([2])` instead of `line.split()[2]`?  Maybe you could just copy paste the code of the answer?

Comment: @JohanC brother honestly thank you so much with your help and advice I have finally done it thank you so very much I am very grateful thank you bro made my day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code mimics reading a file via `StringIO`, to make the example code self-containing. In your code you can just keep reading from the file.

For each line in the file, the code first tests whether it can have useful information, here testing the line length to be at least 10. Then, the start of the line is checked: if the line starts with `"Event ID:"`, we split the line and take the 3<sup>rd</sup> part to `eve`. If the line starts with `"Event Count:"`, the 3<sup>rd</sup> part is converted to an integer and appended to `eventcount`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import StringIO

file_contents = '''
Event ID: 1102
Event Count: 15

Event ID: 4611
Event Count: 2

Event ID: 4624
Event Count: 46

Event ID: 4634
Event Count: 1
'''

eve = []
eventcount = []

# with open("path", 'r') as visualise: # when really reading from a file
with StringIO(file_contents) as visualise: # when mimicking a file with a string
    for line in visualise:
        if len(line) > 10:
            if line.startswith("Event ID:"):
                eve.append(line.split()[2])
            elif line.startswith("Event Count:"):
                eventcount.append(int(line.split()[2]))

plt.barh(eve, eventcount, color='springgreen')
plt.xlabel('Event Count')
plt.ylabel('Event ID')
plt.title('EventID Count')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: barh plot]

Comment: for real i feel so unmotivated i literally do not understand, I got a file that has a bunch of the event ids with the count of how many times it has been found and its in a simple text format as shown in the picture at the top and it needs to make a bar graph as you have made but it does not work

Comment: seriously appriciat you helping me and going out of your way honestly but I literally do not know why it does not work for me with the text file I got.

Comment: Does your file look exactly like the example string?  Do you get errors? Do the lists `eve` and `eventcount` get filled in? Are they filled in as expected? Maybe you can run my code exactly as written, and copy-paste part of the file into the string?

Comment: i copied your one and it does not work it comes blank with negative values on the axis I don't get why with no axes

Comment: I have edited the code on the page on what I have made

Comment: when i ran your code i did not amend anything and still did not work on my side its so weird

Comment: So initially i had a nested dictonary which held the ids and the count values at 0 then incremented them by 1 when there was a matched id once that was done and the new count values was incremented to the dictionary i made a log file to store those new values as shown in the pic the format of the log file, now i need to make a bar graph from that log file which has been created that holds the new count value and the id to visualise what happen if that makes sense to you now.